# Conditionally output a field?

Tags: jq

In this example I only want isGreaterThanOne field to be shown if it's true. Here's what I started with (always shown)

```
echo '[{"a":5},{"a":1}]' | jq '[.[] | {value:.a, isGreaterThanOne:(.a>1)}]'
```

I inserted an if statement

```
echo '[{"a":5},{"a":1}]' | jq '[.[] | {value:.a, X:(if .a>1 then "Y" else "N" end) }]'
```

Then got stuck trying to move the field into the conditional. Also it seems like I must have an else with an if

```
echo '[{"a":5},{"a":1}]' | jq '[.[] | {value:.a, (if .a>1 then (K:"Y)" else (L:"N") end) }]'
```

I want the below as the result (doesn't need to be pretty printed)

```
[
{
    "value": 5,
    "X": "Y"
},
{
    "value": 1,
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `if`, make one branch provide an empty object `{}` which wouldn't contain the extra field:

```bash
map({value: .a} + if .a > 1 then {X: "Y"} else {} end)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/O11MA4l5Azl)

Alternatively, equip only `select`ed items with the extra field:

```bash
map({value: .a} | select(.value > 1).X = "Y")
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1rjolXHjqNQ)

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "value": 5,
    "X": "Y"
  },
  {
    "value": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: It works but I can't seem to get it working in my more complex example. Is there a way to do it without using map?

Comment: @Ned `map(f)` is just a [shortcut](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L3) to `[.[] | f]`, which is the formatting you were using in your question. So, try `[.[] | {value: .a} + if .a > 1 then {X: "Y"} else {} end]` ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/2Pu_u6SnmL_Q)), and if it's not working either, maybe update your question with more of that complexity.